# How to deal with MemoryError in remote ipython notebook?

Tags: numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I am solving certain task on a remote ipython notebook (calculating the pairwise distance of a vector)

code used

```
X = pdist(X, 'mahalanobis', VI=None)
```

vector X is quite huge, so I got a MemoryError

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-69c412a258e0> in <module>()
----> 1 X = pdist(X, 'mahalanobis',     VI=None)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.pyc in     pdist(X, metric, p, w, V, VI)
1183 
1184     m, n = s
-> 1185     dm = np.zeros((m * (m - 1)) // 2, dtype=np.double)
1186 
1187     wmink_names = ['wminkowski', 'wmi', 'wm', 'wpnorm']

MemoryError:
```

Is there anyway I could increase the memory and success the computation ?

Comment: The error means that you ran out of RAM, does that help?

Comment: is that the RAM on my computer or RAM on remote ipython notebook Server ?

Comment: The ram on the remote server